# Python subprocess doesn't execute if the path contains home directory tilde ~

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to detect an error and restart server from django application.
I'm using the following code:

```
try:
 # do something
except:
 print('here')
 subprocess.call(['/home/my_username/restart.sh'])
```

restart.sh is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/my_username/webapps/app/apache2/bin/restart
/home/my_username/webapps/my_db/bin/cron
```

I'm using webfaction as hosting provider.
Aboved code prints statement, but doesn't restart the server and doesn't start mysql database which is under my_db.

Maybe I need to supply username/pass? How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tilde (~) isn't working in subprocess.Popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662821/tilde-isnt-working-in-subprocess-popen)

Comment: I duped to a newer question, because this one has been edited since posting in a way that invalidated it as a good dupe target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `subprocess.call` won't expand the `~` tilde character to your home directory, and therefore it'll look into your current working directory for a folder called **~** and then from there look for your app

You can use the `os.path.expanduser` function to get the desired behaviour, it'll be something like this:

```
try:
 # do something
except:
 print('here')
 subprocess.call([os.path.expanduser('~/webapps/app/apache2/bin/restart')])
```

This script will look for `/home/user/webapps/app/apache2/bin/restart` and execute it.

Good luck ;)