# Tilde (~) isn't working in subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, dd

When I run in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=~/file bs=8k count=200k; rm -f ~/file
```

it works fine.

If I run it through Pythons `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
output, err = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'dd', 'if=/dev/' + disk, 'of=~/disk_benchmark_file', 'bs=8k', 'count=200k'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print err
```

it doesn't work. The Error I get is:

> dd: failed to open '~/disk_benchmark_file': No such file or directory

If I change in the `Popen()` call the tilde `~` to `/home/user`, then it works!

Why is it like that? **And more important to me: How can I make it work?**
 I don't know what the user name will be in production.

Comment: Have you tried with `$HOME`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to wrap those pathnames with [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/disk_benchmark_file')
'/home/dan/disk_benchmark_file'
```

In your code the occurrence of:

```
['sudo', 'dd', 'if=/dev/' + disk, 'of=~/disk_benchmark_file', 'bs=8k', 'count=200k']
```

should be replaced with:

```
['sudo', 'dd', 'if=/dev/' + disk, 'of=' + os.path.expanduser('~/disk_benchmark_file'), 'bs=8k', 'count=200k']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import shlex

outfile = os.path.expanduser('~/file')
cmd_string = 'sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=%s bs=8k count=200k; rm -f %s' % (outfile, outfile)
cmd_list = shlex.split(cmd_string)

# Then use cmd_list as argument for Popen
```

`shlex.split` is the standard and safest way to produce the list that must be used as `command` in subprocess. It is able to handle all the exception and make your code easier to read

You can find the `home` using `os.path.expanduser('~')`.

Comment: `os.path` does not have an `expand` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice thing this shlex.

Answer (score 4):

`~` is a shortcut in the shell for home.  In order for your command to be interpreted by the shell you need to set `shell=True` in your Popen.

The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Note, there are some warnings about doing this though.

Comment: Never recommend using `shell=True`.

Comment: nice explanation :-) Since `shell=True` is discouraged, I guess the solution will be with os.path.expand

Comment: Thanks @RichArt, use with caution, but most of the reasons to discourage it are based on sanitization security issues.  If this isn't production code and you control the input you should be fine.  Unless you only deal in absolutes like Dan D.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the leading `~` in the path to the user's home directory before passing it to `Popen`. You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) for this:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('~/disk_benchmark_file').expanduser()
```

Alternatively, you can use `Path.home()` to get the home directory:

```
Path(Path.home(), 'disk_benchmark_file')
```